# animate jQuery not write correct with css attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know probably I have wrong something! But what?

```
 $(".page-splash-page").bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(){
    $(this).animate({
        -webkit-animation: slide-out-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both,
        -moz-animation: slide-out-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both,
        animation: slide-out-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both,
          }, 1000, function() {
              { window.location.href = "http:..../work/"; }
          });
    });
$(".page-splash-page").on("click touchstart", function () {
     $(this).animate({
        -webkit-animation: slide-out-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both,
        -moz-animation: slide-out-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both,
        animation: slide-out-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both,
          }, 1000, function() {
              { window.location.href = "http:...../work/"; }
          });
    });
$(".page-splash-page").on("touchmove", function() {
     $(this).animate({
        -webkit-animation: slide-out-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both,
        -moz-animation: slide-out-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both,
        animation: slide-out-top 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both,
          }, 1000, function() {
              { window.location.href = "http:..../work/"; }
          });
    });
```

Sorry I hope this function could work but i'm not so expert about js or jQuery!
Some on can help me! thank you!

Comment: animate  an `animation` ???? That is just wrong just add a new class with that animation and then time out to go to the window.location

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For starters, you should look at the dev console for errors.

Comment: If an object property name contains special characters like `-` you need to put it in quotes. There's no way your code will even compile, let alone do what you want.

Comment: @DaniP Thank you, So I give an `AddClass` to the page and in the class use the css code exactly?

Comment: I think you need to use `$.css()` instead (or add a class with these properties) with a `setTimeout` to do the `window.location.href` change. I converted your last block - try something like this for the rest of them http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KWydNR?editors=1010

Comment: Btw sorry if I'm not so expert about js and I try to use ti for the first time. If was a able I never write here... Thank for your down vote...

Comment: @MichaelCoker yeah! this could be a great idea! let me try! I use css because on the documentation using css like example. But now try this. Thank you

Comment: Don't worry mate for the downvoters .... yes you need in this case to `addClass()` will be better

Comment: @MichaelCoker I have try use .css but the animation not work and go directly in the other page. In the solution in the Answer work better but is not fluid. Anyway Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first you are mixing jQuery animate and CSS animations.

I have added a simple pen here that will animate the page-splash-page on click up by -500px. Hopefully this can help you get started:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpOabq

```
$(".page-splash-page").on("click", function() {
 $(this).animate({
  top:'-500px',
      }, 1000, function() {
          { window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com' }
      });
});
```

Comment: Hi @mrsq, first thank you, your code work after I have change the position of the element in Relative. But the things wired is the animation  the animation is jerky, is not smooth, it move in 3 steps... You know why?

Comment: It might be the mousewheel, DOMMouseScroll, touchmove, touchstart events are interfering with each other. Can you leave all of those out and just try a click event by itself.

Comment: I have try but still not work well... Anyway your answer put me in the good road! hope I can fix it!